# High level print function for C++

Tags: c++

Is there a way to create a function or a macro in C++ that you can use like Python?
What i mean is a function like:

```
print(i); // i is an integer.
print(i, s); // i is an integer, s is a std::string. They are separated by a white space.
```

A function that takes in a number of arguments, then just prints them out regardless of the types.

Comment: `std::cout << i << s << std::endl`

Comment: While the python technique seems slick on first sight, and `<<` seems sensible at first as well, it is my experience that both methods quickly fail: It's hard and/or very verbose to try to control the formatting precisely. I've come to love the old C-style `printf()` *long after* I learned to use C++ streams. And now I'm using `printf()` exclusively. Because `printf()` gives me precise, concise control over how the string appears to the user.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica: In some cases too, the `ostream` overheads are a performance bottleneck. Yes, I too prefer `printf` in many situations. I prefer the C++ stuff for reading from standard input, and C stuff for standard output.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Python sting formatting is a lot like `printf` plus type-safety and extensibility.

Comment: @Bathsheba I too prefer C-printf family output functions. The main problem is that they can't be easily extended for custom types like overloading `operator<<`. I've heard that some implementations allow you to [register](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html) a new `printf` function, but that's a bit too much work in my opinion.

Comment: @Bathsheba Oh, `scanf()` can be quite useful as well. If you are using the glibc, that is. Because the glibc provides the `"m"` modifier that will allocate a memory buffer to fit the input into a `"%ms"` or `"%m["` conversion. This makes string input safe. And then there's the feature that `scanf()` will return exactly the number of conversions it has performed successfully. That's invaluable for doing concise input and precise error handling at the same time. That's the way I see it, though I don't have much opportunity to hone my input parsing skills.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica I think the `m` modifier is a POSIX thing.

Comment: @Ayxan Yes, I fully agree that that's a pitfall of `printf()`. I usually solve it by providing a per-object print function that takes a `FILE*` argument. Together with `open_memstream()` that allows output to both files and strings. But it cannot extend the `printf()` syntax, which is a pity.

Comment: @Ayxan Yes, you are right. The `m` modifier is indeed part of the POSIX standard. I confused it with the older `a` modifier which was a suboptimal GNU extension. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 8):

If you are allowed to use C++17, you can do it using fold-expression, like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<class ...Args>
void print(const Args &...args) {
    auto seq_started = false;
    auto print_impl = [&](auto &value) mutable {
        if (seq_started) {
            std::cout << " " << value;
        } else {
            seq_started = true;
            std::cout << value;
        }
    };
    
    (print_impl(args), ...);
}

int main() {
    print("foo", 10, "bar", 20, "baz");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was wondering why you need to do extra `seq_started` variable there when you use a fold-expression. You do not need that, see here [How do I print out the arguments of a function using a variadic template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342633/how-do-i-print-out-the-arguments-of-a-function-using-a-variadic-template/63434791#63434791)

Answer (score 7):

Use streams:

```cpp
std::cout << i << ' ' << s << '\n';
```

For more complex formatting consider [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), it supports the syntax for python's `str.format` as well as `printf` style formatting (but typesafe).

Answer (score 6):

I assume that the question is about general solution and that `print` is just an example.

The answer is: yes, with a combination of overloads and templates. First you setup functions per type:

```cpp
void print_impl(const std::string& arg) {
    std::cout << arg;
}

void print_impl(int arg) {
    // Note: this is an example. Of course cout already
    // does that for us with simple
    //   std::cout << arg;
    print_impl(convert_to_string(arg));
}

// cout already has lots of overloads, we can take
// advantage of that if needed:
template<class TArg>
void print_impl(TArg&& arg) {
    std::cout << std::forward<TArg>(arg);
}
```

then templates:

```cpp
template<class TArg>
void print(TArg&& arg) {
    print_impl(std::forward<TArg>(arg));
}

template<class TArg1, class ... TArgs>
void print(TArg1&& arg1, TArgs&& ... args) {
    print_impl(std::forward<TArg1>(arg1));   // <-- print first argument
    print_impl(" ");   // <-- insert separator, requires const std::string& overload
    print(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);   // <-- recursive call
}
```

In the code above you can replace calls to `print_impl` with calls to `std::cout <<` operator directly, if needed. Although I would keep `print_impl` because it is a nice layer above `std::cout` in case you want to replace it in the future.

Then you can use it similar to Python:

```cpp
int main()
{
    print("test");
    print(1, 2, "foo");
    print("foo", 1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, why do you have the separate `print_impl` functions for the `int` and the `const std::string&`? What am I missing?

Comment: @Bathsheba I've updated the answer. This particular example was perhaps misleading because `cout` already has different implementations based on type. I wanted to show that you can have different implementations based on type.