how to print string3 = string1 + string2 as "string1 string2 in c++
So I'm working on a little project to help me learn more about stings and about linked lists. This is my first time using c++ as I usually use C
I have my header file MyString.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>

class String
{
private:
    char* str;
public:
    String();
    String(const char* s);
    ~String();
    char* GetString();
    ////////
    int GetLength()
    {
        return std::strlen(str);
    }
    String& operator = (const char* s);
    char& operator[] (int index);
    String& operator +(String& s);
};

and my MyString.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "MyString.h"
#include <cassert>

String::String()
{
    str = nullptr;
}

String::String(const char* s)
{
    int len = strlen(s);
    str = new char[len+1];
    strcpy(str, s);
}

String::~String()
{
    std::cout << "clean string: ";
    if (str == nullptr)
        std::cout << "nullptr";
    else
        std::cout << str;
    std::cout << "\n";
    if (str != nullptr)
        delete [] str;
}

char* String::GetString()
{
    return str;
}

String& String::operator=(const char* s)
{
    // TODO: insert return statement here
    if (str != nullptr)
    {
        delete[] str;
    }
    int len = strlen(s);
    str = new char[len + 1];
    strcpy(str, s);
    return *this;
}

char& String::operator[](int index)
{
    assert(index >= 0 && index < GetLength());

    return str[index];
}

I'm trying to make it work where if I try this
String s1 = "Hello";
String s2 = "There";
s3 = s1 + s2;
Print(s3.GetString());

It would print as "Hello There"
but im lost on how to write a function where even if i add more strings it automatically formats it and prints it.
I can do this for example
std::string s3 = s1 + " " + s2;

but I don't want to do it for each individual print statement.

The "add" operator (operator+) should not modify any of the strings. It should create a new string and return that.

you have to implemenet a + operator. Did you try to do that? THough +  adding a ' ' I do not consider as a good idea

I recommend you take some time to read this canonical implementation reference to see a good way to implement operator+.

its not totally clear what you are asking. You have a operator+ declared but not defined. Its not clear if you do have some implmentation and merely need to add a ' ' or if you have no definition at all

Before you move forward with operator+ you have: big problem with defaulted copy constructor, also when playing with this kind of excise I would recommend to learn  how to write unit test. Catch2 is most user friendly testing framework. Here you can try it online: https://godbolt.org/z/j1s8jYKj6 As you can see basic test already found another bug in your code.

It appears you'd like to print out the arguments of a variadic function.  Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63434791/4641116

Problem is that your current code has lots of basic bugs.
I really recommend you to learn how to write unit test (to test code). This is one of most important skills in programing. Catch2 is most user friendly testing framework.
Here is some live demo for you existing code detecting bunch of problems:
TEST_CASE("My String")
{
    SECTION("defult Constructed")
    {
        String s;
        REQUIRE(s.GetLength() == 0);
        SECTION("assiging an literal")
        {
            s = "some literal";
            REQUIRE(s.GetLength() != 0);
        }
    }
    SECTION("constructed from literal")
    {
        String s { "my test string" };
        REQUIRE(s.GetLength() != 0);
    }
}

I see following issues:

GetLength crashes on default constructed string (detected by test I've provided)
you need define custom copy constructor and assign operator (add test for it yourself), now default implementation lead to memory issues. See The rule of three/five/zero.
you have problem with const correctnes
you need some functionality to compare strings (add test for that too).

When you address above then you can add test for operator+ and define this operator+:
class String {
....
    String operator+(const String& other) const;
};

